# How to stop Windows 10 from reconnecting to shares in background

Tags: windows

I noticed after viewing network traffic, that after you connect to one computer's network share from another computer in an AD environment, that Windows 10 continuously reconnects to that share at random times until the end of time, even after reboots, and even though the share is no longer visible in any obvious area. I guess this is to increase future connection times by 3.1 microseconds.

How do I get Windows 10 to forget which shares it has connected to, to stop this misleading traffic at random times that shows lateral communication between workstations?

Answer (score 0):

**(1)** Use NET USE T: /Delete for all drives  that have been mapped. Verify with NET USE (no parameters) to see there are no drives.

If these are simple network shares, step one may be sufficient.

**(1) b** You can turn Persistence OFF on mapped drives but I do not really recommend this.

**(2)** You can also Delete the drive immediately before mapping it if scripted to keep drive mappings clean.

**(3)** If you wish to investigate it (somewhat more complicated) you can build a logoff script that will run whenever you log off or shut down.  The logoff script is a batch file that will delete all connections you normally use.  You need the local Group Policy Editor for this.

Comment: Its not actually a mapped drive, its just connecting to a network share.

Comment: You can still delete network shares to keep them from automatically re-appearing. I made an amendment to my answer to reflect this.

Comment: The only thing listed in `net use` are mapped drives which need to stay, not network shares which were accessed one time weeks ago via a UNC path in explorer. There is no where that I can find that references these old shares, Windows simply reconnects in the background until the end of time it seems.

Comment: Then you will need to manually disconnect drives. Right click on the drive and select disconnect. You may wish to start mapping drives as connect and disconnect is easier.

Comment: There is nothing to disconnect or right click, its not a mapped drive as I have repeatedly said. There is no indication anywhere in the gui or command line tools that show anything being mapped. The only indication is repeated network requests to computers that have a share that has been connected to in the distant past.

Comment: Perhaps turn Browsing off and map normally. I use mapped drives on productions machines.  I have one Windows Insider machine where I connected by right clicking and connecting and the drive does not reconnect after. So it must be the form of connecting you are using. Normal connecting works a whole lot better.

Comment: Also look in your local group policy editor to see if you have a script connecting and reconnecting the drive / folder